# How to Read in Words and Add it in a Table According to the Word

Tags: r

I am trying to have R read in the words in each column and add them to a table based on if each player did that event.

**Dataset I am trying to get information from:**

```
structure(list(Players = c("Mandy", "Jlin", "Gray", "Kiersten", 
"Kelsey", "Karlie", "Jordan", "Lilly", "McCarter", "Emma", "Alia", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Subs = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Mance", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), FSU = c("6 good alia tackle", 
"1 bad", "them pi", "2 good 1 bad", "7 good 1 bad", "them pi", 
"2 good 1 bad", "them pi", "8 good them turnover", "them pi", 
"3 good 1 bad", "them pi", "4 good kelsey tackle them turnover", 
"them pi", "6 good them shot saved mandy SOG", "them pi", "8 good 1 bad", 
"them pi", "1 bad"), PI = c("jordan", "mccarter", "kiersten", 
"jordan", "jlin", "alia", "mandy", "mandy", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), TI = c("them ti good 8 good 1 bad", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Cleared = c("jordan", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Corner = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), Tackles = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Free Kicks` = c("kelsey free kick to gray bad", 
"them free kick short good 3 good jordan fouls", "them free kick bad", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), Fouls = c("lilly fouls", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), VT = c("jordan to karlie karlie turnover unforced", 
"jlin to gray bad", "alia to kiersten to lilly to kiersten bad", 
"mandy to karlie bad", "kelsey to mccarter to jordan to emma emma fouled", 
"mandy to karlie bad", "mandy to kiersten cleared bad", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 19L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I was able to read in the passes and add a tally to each player and to who they passed it to using the following code below:

```
pass = sub('_$','_good',sub("(.*\\w+ to (?:\\w+(?=.*(bad))|\\w+)).*",'\\1_\\2',dat$VT,perl = T))
pass1 = gsub('(to(\\s[^_ ]+(?=\\s)))','\\1_good\n\\2',pass,perl=T)
results = xtabs(V3~.,cbind(read.csv(text=gsub('to',',',pass1),h=F,strip.white = T),V3=1))

results
          V2
V1         emma_good gray_bad jordan_good karlie_bad karlie_good kiersten_bad kiersten_good lilly_good mccarter_good
  alia             0        0           0          0           0            0             1          0             0
  jlin             0        1           0          0           0            0             0          0             0
  jordan           1        0           0          0           1            0             0          0             0
  kelsey           0        0           0          0           0            0             0          0             1
  kiersten         0        0           0          0           0            0             0          1             0
  lilly            0        0           0          0           0            1             0          0             0
  mandy            0        0           0          2           0            1             0          0             0
  mccarter         0        0           1          0           0            0             0          0             0
```

Since I have good and passes working as expected, I am wondering if someone would be able to help me read the other columns. But for now, I would like to find a way to complete the intercepted passes column (in my data set it is the column "PI"), so modeling it off of the table for passes, after some code is called, it should result in something looking like this:

```
Player           PI
Mandy             2
Jlin              1
Gray              0
Kiersten          1
Kelsey            0
Karlie            0
Jordan            2
Lilly             0
McCarter          1
Emma              0
Alia              1
```

Thanks, Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the frequency count by converting the 'PI' column to a `factor` class with `levels` specified as the 'Players' and wrap it with `table`.  Note that there is inconsistency in the case in both columns.  To match those columns, we change it to lower case

```
table(factor(tolower(dat$PI), levels = tolower(na.omit(dat$Players)),
        labels = na.omit(dat$Players)))

#  Mandy     Jlin     Gray Kiersten   Kelsey   Karlie   Jordan    Lilly McCarter     Emma     Alia 
#      2        1        0        1        0        0        2        0        1        0        1
```

---

Or make the first letter in the 'PI' to upper case and then do the `table`

```
tbl <- table(factor(sub("^(.)", "\\U\\1", na.omit(dat$PI),
          perl = TRUE), levels = na.omit(dat$Players)))
tbl
#   Mandy     Jlin     Gray Kiersten   Kelsey   Karlie   Jordan    Lilly McCarter     Emma     Alia 
#    2        1        0        1        0        0        2        0        0        0        1
```

It can be converted to a two column data.frame

```
out <- data.frame(Player = names(tbl), PI = as.vector(tbl))
```

---

Or this can be done with a pipe

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  transmute(PI = factor(tolower(PI), levels = tolower(na.omit(Players)),
       labels = na.omit(Players))) %>% 
  na.omit %>%
  count(PI, .drop = FALSE)
```